# TypeError: t.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, mapping

The problem I'm dealing with is TypeError: t.map is not a function
I'm trying to map my array of jsons to the React components to render them with props.

```
function App() {
    const charts = renderUserProjects();
    return(
    <div className="app-container">
        <h1 className="app-title">Welcome back! Here are your trackings: </h1>
        <div className="trackings-container">
            <h2 className="trackings-title">‍ Watchlist</h2>
            {
                charts.map(chart => (
                    <Collection {...chart} key={chart.symbol} />
                ))
            }
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

}

I'm mapping the charts array above and I'm creating it below

```
const renderUserProjects = async() => {
    const userProjects = await fetchUserProjects();
    const charts = []
    for(let x = 0; x < userProjects.length; x++) {
        try {
            const proxyURL = 'https://ixoth-tracker.herokuapp.com/';
            const targetURL = 'https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections/' + userProjects[x] + '/stats';
            const response = await axios.get(proxyURL + targetURL);
            const data = response.data
            const floorPrice = data["floorPrice"];
            const listedCount = data["listedCount"];
            const volumeAll = data["volumeAll"];
            let chartJSON = {
                symbol: userProjects[x],
                floorPrice: floorPrice,
                listedCount: listedCount,
                volumeAll: volumeAll
            }
            charts.push(JSON.stringify(chartJSON))
        } catch(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
    console.log(charts)
    return(charts);
}
```

I looked up on google and most of the errors caused because the element that is being mapped was not an array (usually an object). But in my case I don't think the problem is that, I tried to console.log(Array.isArray(charts)) and it printed out true
Can someone help me with this problem?

```
function Collection(props) {
return(
    <div className="chart-wrapper">
        <p className="project-name">{props.symbol}</p>
        <p className="floor-price">Floor Price: {props.floorPrice}</p>
        <p className="listed-count">Listed Count: {props.listedCount}</p>
        <p className="volume-all">Volume All: {props.volumeAll}</p>
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: can you share some code to reproduce your error.?

Comment: Which file and line produced the error?

Comment: I added more lines of code, you can use random data jsons for the array

Comment: the error was caused by the line that starts with charts.map inside App()

Comment: Try this instead:
charts.map(chart => ({
<Collection {...chart} key={chart.symbol} />
}))
Also I believe that .map() will not work in this scenario unless you return an object.

Comment: doesn't seem to work, it throws a syntax error

Comment: could you try using a for-loop instead of .map()

Comment: I couldn't come up with a nice solution with a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `renderUserProjects` is **async function.** It returns `Promise` which doesn't have map method. At the moment of rendering, it hasn't been even resolved. Moreover, each component render you start data fetching.

In this case, we have to wait until it's resolved.

```
function App() {
    // We put [] as default value. Or we can add even a `loading` state in order to show spinner during the data fetching.
    const [charts, setCharts] = useState([]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
        // On mount
        renderUserProjects().then(setChart);
    }, []);
    
    return(
       <div className="app-container">
```

or as the second option, we can transform `renderUserProjects` to custom hook `useUserProjectCharts` and do the same here:

```
const useRenderUserProjects = () => {
  const [charts, setCharts] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState();
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  async function getCharts() {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const userProjects = await fetchUserProjects();
    const charts = [];

    for (let x = 0; x < userProjects.length; x++) {
      const proxyURL = 'https://ixoth-tracker.herokuapp.com/';
      const targetURL = 'https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections/' + userProjects[x] + '/stats';
      const response = await axios.get(proxyURL + targetURL);
      const data = response.data;
      const floorPrice = data['floorPrice'];
      const listedCount = data['listedCount'];
      const volumeAll = data['volumeAll'];
      let chartJSON = {
        symbol: userProjects[x],
        floorPrice: floorPrice,
        listedCount: listedCount,
        volumeAll: volumeAll,
      };

      charts.push(JSON.stringify(chartJSON));
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getCharts()
      .then(setCharts)
      .catch(setError)
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return { charts, isLoading, error };
};
```

and use it `useRenderUserProjects` as in your App component:

```
const charts = useRenderUserProjects();
```